# Views JSON output

Tags: views, 8

**Can anyone tell me how I can get plain JSON output with no surrounding HTML?**

I am using the Views and Views JSON modules to get my node data as JSON output.

The problem is my JSON output still comes embedded in the default Drupal theme. I set the default theme to stark hoping that I will not see any HTML in the output but that did not work.

My attempts to set the theme for the View did not work either.

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Views JSON" is obsolete and "Views Datasource" is D7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Go to the configuration of your Views display which produces the JSON
  output.
- Click on the **Settings** link of the **JSON data document
  format**.
- Make sure that ***Views API mode*** is **not enabled**. The description of this setting explains it all:

  > Not using View API mode means the JSON gets output directly and the
  >   server ceases normal page processing. Using it means the server does
  >   not cease processing after outputting the JSON. This allows the Views
  >   API to be used with the view without having to prematurely terminate
  >   page processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Views Datasource](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... is a set of plugins for Drupal Views for rendering content in a number of shareable, reusable formats based on XML, JSON and XHTML. These formats allow content in a Drupal site to be easily used as data sources for Semantic Web clients and web mash-ups. Views Datasource plugins output content from node lists created in the Drupal Views interface in a variety of formats - XML data documents using schemas like OPML and Atom, RDF data documents using a vocabulary like FOAF, JSON data documents in a format like Exhibit JSON, and XHTML data documents using a microformat like hCard.
>
> Views Datasource can be thought of as a userland complement to the work going on in the Services and RDF APIs as a site operator only needs to know Views to be able to create datasources in the different formats.
>
> The project consists of 4 Views style plugins (and related row plugins):
>
> - views_xml - Output as raw XML, OPML, and Atom;
> - views_json - Output as Simile/Exhibit JSON, Canonical JSON, JSONP/JSON in script;
> - views_rdf- Output as FOAF, SIOC, and DOAP;
> - views_xhtml - Output as hCard, hCalendar, and Geo.

Comment: The *Views JSON* module is shipped with *Views Datasource*.

Comment: Ahh, ic. I've never used it myself.

Comment: But for D7 it is still in dev and last release date is "2012-Jun-15".